# Can I use CSS to create full-width slider that preserves the aspect ratio of the contents?

Tags: jquery, css, unslider

I'm currently using [unslider](http://unslider.com/) to create a full width slider header on a webpage (http://fths.convoke.info). It works fine at the dimensions I designed it at (1920x450), but on different resolutions, things get weird. Take a look:

[image: Gap between slider and menu]

The background image is scaled proportionally so that its width fits on the screen, but the actual `li` element has a fixed height and doesn't resize, leaving the gap shown in the picture.

Here's the HTML for the slider setup itself:

```
<div class="banner" style="overflow: hidden; width: 1904px; height: 450px;">
    <ul style="width: 300%; position: relative; left: -200%; height: 450px;">
        <li style="width: 33.333333333333336%; background-image: url(http://fths.convoke.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/header450-02.jpg); background-size: 100%;"></li>
        <li style="width: 33.333333333333336%; background-image: url(http://fths.convoke.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/header450-01.jpg); background-size: 100%;"></li>
        <li style="width: 33.333333333333336%; background-image: url(http://fths.convoke.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/header450-03.jpg); background-size: 100%;"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.banner li { list-style: none; }
.banner ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I tried various combinations of `min-height` and `max-height`, but I couldn't really get it to work. The height needs to have *some* value, otherwise the `li` elements collapse on themselves. `background-size:cover` also seems promising, but then the image doesn't scale at all, and looks bad at very narrow resolutions.

In order for this to work, I think I need a way to set the height of the `li` so that it maintains the same relative proportions as the background images. Is there some way to do this with CSS, or do I need to script something? I found [this method](http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/11/responsive-background-images-with-fixed-or-fluid-aspect-ratios) that "sets" the height by using `padding-top:x%`, but I think this causes problems because the actual width of the slider changes depending on how many slides there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with pure css, but it is possible to with a simple JQuery function as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h06jg6u/1/).

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  function setImageHeight(){
    var bannerWidth = $('.banner').width();
    var imageHeight = 450 * bannerWidth/1903;
    $('.banner ul li').css('height', imageHeight.toString());
  }

  setImageHeight();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    setImageHeight();
  });

});
```

Comment: Fiddle looks great! I will try to implement it and let you know how it turns out. Thank you!

Comment: So, I finally got around to trying this script out. First off, thank you very much. It works ALMOST perfectly... the only problem is that the slider has to "slide" once before it updates the height of the li element. It's live on http://fths.convoke.info if you want to see what I mean. If you scale your browser window, then load the page, for the first slide, it will still have a lot of black space above and below. But, after a few seconds, it moves on to the second slide, and the element updates its height. Is there anyway to get it to update on the initial load?

Comment: For the record, I put the script in the footer. Maybe that's the problem... it's getting called after the height is being set initially.

Comment: heh... yeah, looks like moving it to the header fixed the problem. Thank you again so much @klasske!